# NextJs redux persist prevent show DOM in view page source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am building app with NextJs + Redux persist. For SEO purpose I expect to show DOM Content (inside the defaul div#__next of NextJs) when view page source. It's ok without add PersistGate to component /pages/_app.js.

But if I add PersistGate, no DOM content shown in page source. I have searched on Internet as well as docs of redux persist but no information. Can anyone give me an advice?

My codes /pages/_app.js:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistor, store } from 'src/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {/* <PersistGate persistor={persistor}> */} **if uncomment this line, no DOM content shown in view page source**
            <main>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </main>
            {/* </PersistGate> */}
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

code of redux persist,
store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import RootReducer from './root-reducer';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'vm',
    storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, RootReducer);

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

root-reducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import appReducer from './app/reducer';

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
    App: appReducer,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find the answer? As I'm also facing same issue?

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately I have not found any way excepting remove redux. Try to use getServerSideProps, this function provide context including params, query parameters, etc so you can call api base on context. Good luck

Comment: In case you really need to use Redux, just remove redux persist, this will work

Comment: Just find a way: in App.js component, use this code {() => <Component {...pageProps} />} instead of <Component {...pageProps} />

Comment: Try to use useEffect.